# Way of adding/removing EF entities via checkboxes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model which contains an array of ints (model.ProductCheckedIds) which represents checked products on the UI.

I also have an EF entity (lead) with child entities (LeadProducts).

I came up with this solution to remove any child items that are now de-selected, and add any that are newly selected.

Can this be code simplified or improved upon?

```
    var addIds = model.ProductCheckedIds.Except(lead.LeadProducts.Select(x => x.ProductId));
    var toAdd = addIds.Select(addId => new LeadProduct {LeadId = model.LeadId, ProductId = addId}).ToList();

    var removeIds = lead.LeadProducts.Select(x => x.ProductId).Except(model.ProductCheckedIds);
    var toRemove = removeIds.Select(removeId => lead.LeadProducts.Single(x => x.ProductId == removeId)).ToList();

    toRemove.ForEach(x=>lead.LeadProducts.Remove(x));
    toAdd.ForEach(x => lead.LeadProducts.Add(x));
```

Comment: I don't know if it can be improved, but it's better than the way I did a similar thing the other day, so thanks, and have my vote up!

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a way of being able to do this without having to attach objects to EF which I've done previously.

Comment: This is a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, can I move it across or should I just re-copy the question on CodeReview?